# Peut-on dire « La somme soit prise sur les x qui satisfont P(x) » ?

Tags: mathématiques

Parfois, par concision, on utilise un *sigma* majuscule pour indiquer qu’on prend une somme. Sous ce *sigma*, on écrit quel ensemble l’indéterminée muette doit parcourir.

Cependant il est parfois dur de représenter quelque chose par formule, ou, si on a trouvé une formule qui convient, elle est parfois trop grande pour l’enchâsser. Alors on décrit dans une phrase à quelle partie l’indéterminée muette doit appartenir. Je cherche une bonne phrase pour exprimer cette appartenance.

Peut-on dire : « La somme soit prise sur les *x* qui satisfont *P(x)* », si *P(x)* désigne une propriété quelconque de *x* ?

Y a-t-il d'autres façons habiles de dire que l’indéterminée muette doit remplir une exigence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La formule habituelle pour exprimer ceci dans les articles de mathématiques est:

> La somme porte sur l'ensemble des *x* qui satisfont *P(x)* / tels que *P(x)*.

On peut aussi dire « La somme est prise… », mais « soit » est une erreur.

Par exemple, on pourra dire :

> *Σ<sub>x</sub> f(x)*, où la somme porte / est prise sur l'ensemble des *x* tels que *2x* est un carré.

Comment: Est prise *dans*.

Comment: @ Stéphane Gimenez,  Êtez-vous sûr? En fait d’une preuve récurrente on dit « sur », c’est-à-dire qu’on montre quelque chose par récurrence *sur* un nombre. On dit pareillement, si je ne me trompe pas, qu’un polynôme ne possède pas de racines *sur* un corps donné. Ma langue maternelle emploie la même tournure.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin: Oups, oui, d'une certaine façon tu as raison. Le problème est le choix du verbe en fait. « Être pris dans » peut être utilisé mais pas pour une somme. On dirait « est faite sur » dans ce cas.

Comment: @Stehane Gimenez: Vous avez raison, "est prise sur" est moins naturel - mais je ne jurerai pas de ne pas l'avoir lu. Après tout, on dit à l'oral "On prend la somme sur l'ensemble X..." et je trouve "La somme est faite" également un peu maladroit. "Porte sur" est certainement mon premier choix.